# How to flush cache line in apple M1

Tags: caching, arm, cpu, apple-m1, arm64

I tried the  "DC CIVAC ...." instruction in Arm-V8 ISA to clear a cache line for apple M1. But seems it didn't work for flushing one cache line. Did anyone successfully flush the cache line on M1?

Comment: How do you know it didn't work?  What is your test case?

Comment: For a memory address addr, firstly I access it for some times(make sure it is in the cache ). Then I measure the memory access time of addr(in the cache) as t1. Next I use   "DC CIVAC ...." instruction to flush the cache line. Then measure the access time t2. I find t1 is almost equal to t2.

Comment: Did you remember to `dsb sys` after `dc civac` to wait for the flush to complete?  Otherwise AFAIK cache flushes don't complete immediately; the `dc` instruction just queues the flush to be done in the background.  Also, how are you measuring the time?

Comment: Here is the code I used. [test case](https://github.com/zyma-Jasper/stackoverflowCode/blob/main/flush_cache_M1.c) I use other's code to set up a kernel module to measure time(the first test for loop time test confirm its correctness). I use the dsb sy and some empty for loop to wait for the flush to finish. Result shows that there is no difference before and after the flush operation.

Comment: You only do the flush and reload once between rdtsc's?  I'd think the overhead and noise of the system call required for rdtsc would swamp the time of a single cache miss.  Main memory is slow but it isn't *that* slow.  I'd try doing it several million times in a loop, and time the total.

Comment: Also, I think your "empty for loop" might defeat its purpose.  The `dsb sys` should already wait for the flush to complete before executing any further instructions.  But while your busy loop runs, the CPU could be prefetching or speculatively loading `buffer`, so that when the loop completes, it's back in L1 cache and ready to go.  I'd take that loop out.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But seems that it still doesn't work. So confusing for the apple M1 architecture.